# scanning for serial numbers

Tags: ms-access, vba, full-text-search

I have some VBA code in Access that scans the body of an email for a specific serial number. The serial number previously started with a 2 followed by three letters, and then 5 Numbers. I was using something like the posted code to search for the most common prefixes. Now they have changed the serial numbers to eliminate the 2 and with my current method this makes grabbing incorrect text much more likely. EMText is a string containing the email body.

The new format is ABC12345D1234 this can pretty much be any combination of letters or numbers, but the letters are always letters and the numbers are always numbers. Is there a quick way to search for something with this specfic length and number of letters and numbers or the specific format. I am having trouble coming up with something that is not overly complicated on my own and can't track down an example that matches what I am trying to do.

```
Function GetUnitNumber(ByVal EMText) As String

    unit = ""

If InStr(1, EMText, "2ABC") Then

    vItem = Split(EMText, "2ABC")
    unit = "2ABC" & Left(vItem(1), 5)

ElseIf (InStr(1, EMText, "2CA")) Then

    vItem = Split(EMText, "2CA")

    unit = "2CA" & Left(vItem(1), 6)

ElseIf (InStr(1, EMText, "2DFS")) Then.......
```

Comment: Why would you want to grab incorrect text? Did you mean 'makes grabbing correct text much more difficult'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical scenario for Regular Expressions.

Link to Microsoft VBScrpt Regular Expressions

And use this:

```
Function GetUnitNumber(ByVal EMText)

Dim regEx As New RegExp

With regEx
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .IgnoreCase = True
    'This matches the pattern: i.e. ABC12345D1234 
    .Pattern = "[A-Z]{3}[0-9]{5}[A-Z]{1}[0-9]{4}"
End With

If regEx.Test(EMText) Then
    GetUnitNumber = regEx.Execute(EMText)(0)
End If

End Function
```